# How to avoid nested IF condition while designing algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm

I have the following pseudocode for algorithm with multiple `IF` conditions. How to avoid such nesting with some checking or more efficient way.

> If (there does not exist a house) then
>
> if (road ==1) then do something
>
> if (road ==2) then do something
>
> if (road ==3) then do something
>
> end if end if end if end if
>
> If (road ==4) AND (there exist a house) then do something end if

Comment: This is largely dependent on the task at hand. Have you considered switch statements?

Comment: @rosscowar here take my thumbs up.
First thing in mind is the switch statement.

In the final case you put an if inside to check for house existence.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeEco it's hard to minify ambiguous tasks but the switch statement isn't always known by green programmers and can be great for making code more readable.

Comment: Thanks. I change like this way. Pls suggest me.
If (there does not exist a house) then
Switch (road) {
case 1: 
do something for case 1
case 2: 
do something for case 2
case 3: 
do something for case 3
case 4: 
If (there exist a house) Then
do something for case 4
End IF
} //close switch
End IF

Comment: It won't work like that, because your whole switch statement is inside the `if(!houseExists)`, so case 4 can never evaluate true. So you'd need `if(!houseExists) { switch (road) { case 1: //stuff; case 2: //stuff; case 3: //stuff} else if (houseExists && road == 4) {//stuff for 4}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably be more concerned about readability than efficiency, unless you have profiled your code and found it is a bottleneck.

For readability you could use an array of classes that implement a common interface. In pseudo code, given this interface:

```
interface Callback
{
    void DoJob()
}
```

and various classes that implement the interface:

```
class DoThing1 implements Callback { public void DoJob() { .. } }
class DoThing2 implements Callback { public void DoJob() { .. } }
```

Then in your main code have an array of these callbacks:

```
Callback m_roadHandlers[MAX_HANDLERS]
```

And call them like so:

```
if (house and road == 4)
    m_roadHandlers[road].DoJob();
else if (no house and road >= 1 and road <= 3)
    m_roadHandlers[road].DoJob();
```

You tagged Java, so I illustrated it as above because Java doesn't (yet) have a notion of method callbacks so as far as I know you can't pass in a method (it's been a while since I used Java), so you might have to pass in the class to the callback. In C# you could use delegates and pass in methods in the same class.

Comment: Your code doesn't duplicate the OP's functionality. In your `if (no house)`, you only want to dispatch if `road` is equal to 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: I updated it. I was really just trying to generalise and explain the idea, but you're right it doesn't completely answer his original question.